# spring cloud config consumer visibility restriction

Tags: spring-cloud-config

Spring cloud : Angel.SR3

I want to restrict(via security) the visibility of what properties a consuming app can see.

app1 sees : app1.properties(yml) + application.properties , 
app2 sees : app2.properties(yml) + application.properties

app1 should not be able to see(accidentally ?) app2.properties

Each app ldap authenticates into the cloud config (environment controller).

Any ideas on how to go about this ?